# Apply symbols in a style sheet(stylex) through code

Tags: style, arcgis-pro-sdk

I'm in the process of converting an ArcMap add-in using ArcObjects to use ArcGIS Pro SDK. Not a fun process I must say.

We need to apply symbologies on the fly through code. In ArcObjects I can find the style sheet(.style file), loop through each symbol by name and return an `ISymbol` object which I can then apply to a ArcMap layer. Is there something similar in Pro SDK? For the life of me I can not find any example anywhere.

I was able to add the style sheet to a Pro project and apply symbols to a layer. With ArcObjects you can basically write code to do anything and everything but I'm not sure if this is the case with Pro SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Found a sample code in the link below;

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/blob/33fc821f4d107ec646624d13fe133e0a61244f33/Examples/MapAuthoring/CartoFeatures/ProSnippet.cs

Here is the snippet I'm using to apply a symbol from a style sheet to a layer in the map. I added the style sheet to the project I'm using before hand but it can be added at run time it seems. Also I have to stick with VB so please ignore the C# related conversation.

```
Dim uniqueValueRenderer As CIMUniqueValueRenderer = New CIMUniqueValueRenderer() With {
        .Fields = New String() {"MAP_DIR"}
        }
Dim classes As List(Of CIMUniqueValueClass) = New List(Of CIMUniqueValueClass)()

Dim tsdStyle As StyleProjectItem = Project.Current.GetItems(Of StyleProjectItem)().FirstOrDefault(Function(s) s.Name = "style sheet name")
Dim styleItem As IList(Of SymbolStyleItem)
Dim tickSymbol As CIMSymbol

        ' EAST
        Dim eastValues As List(Of CIMUniqueValue) = New List(Of CIMUniqueValue)()
        Dim eastValue As CIMUniqueValue = New CIMUniqueValue() With {
                .FieldValues = New String() {"E"}
        }
        eastValues.Add(eastValue)
        styleItem = tsdStyle.SearchSymbols(StyleItemType.PointSymbol, "symbol name")
        tickSymbol = styleItem.FirstOrDefault().Symbol
        Dim east = New CIMUniqueValueClass() With {
                .Values = eastValues.ToArray(),
                .Label = "East",
                .Visible = True,
                .Editable = True,
                .Symbol = New CIMSymbolReference() With {
                .Symbol = tickSymbol
                }
        }
        classes.Add(east)
...
...
...
Dim groupOne As CIMUniqueValueGroup = New CIMUniqueValueGroup() With {
                .Heading = "Tics",
                .Classes = classes.ToArray()
        }
uniqueValueRenderer.Groups = New CIMUniqueValueGroup() {groupOne}
uniqueValueRenderer.UseDefaultSymbol = False
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Great that you were able to find a solution to your problem - please consider making an [edit] to your answer to expand it a bit with the specifics that solved the problem.  This makes it easier for others with the same or similar problem to find the solution.